# jQuery error during phpIPAM database installation

Tags: php, jquery, ubuntu-12.04

I was trying to install phpIPAM on my ubuntu 12.04.4 server. I have followed all the steps required for the installation. I get jQuery error when i try to get to the first step of the installation process i.e database installation. I followed the steps given in this link:

http://phpipam.net/phpipam-installation-on-debian-6-0-6/

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: jQuery error!

Hide
Loading...
phpIPAM | installation
phpIPAM database installation


Please select installation type:
Automatic database installation
MySQL import instructions
Manual install instructions
phpIPAM IP address management [v1.0]  In case of problems please contact Submit

Comment: This is what is logged in the apache error log: PHP Warning:  mysqli::mysqli(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'phpipam'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /var/www/phpipam/functions/dbfunctions.php on line 16, referer: http://10.1.10.65/phpipam/install/

Answer (score 1):

That error means that the combination of username and password supplied to phpIPAM was not valid.

Maybe the user doesn't exist on the database or the you made an error when supplying the credentials to phpIPAM.

You can try logging in directly on the database using the credentials for phpIPAM and that should help you find the cause.

Anymore information can't be deduced from the information currently available.

Comment: This is what i have in the /var/www/phpipam/config.php <?php

/*database connection details
 ******************************/
$db['host'] = "localhost";
$db['user'] = "phpipam";
$db['pass'] = "phpipamadmin";
$db['name'] = "phpipam";

/**
 * php debugging on/off
 *
 * true  = SHOW all php errors
 * false = HIDE all php errors
 ******************************/
$debugging = false;

/**     
 *      BASE definition if phpipam 
 *      is not in root directory (e.g. /phpipam/)
 *
 *  Also change 
 *      RewriteBase / in .htaccess
 ******************************/
define('BASE', "/phpipam");

?>

Comment: I have manually created a user with user=phpipam and password=phpipamadmin. I am trying to get this working, i have configured everything as given in the setup notes. Just doesn't work for me :(